# c# object lengh from variable

Tags: c#, object

When I try something like this

```
DataTable wynikIlosc=API.exported.Database.executeQueryWithResult("select count(*) as ilosc from Przedmioty limit 1");
przedmioty= new object[(int)wynikIlosc.Rows[0]["ilosc"]];
```

I get this error:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
```

When I use this

```
przedmioty= new object[20];
```

it Works.
The same happens with new object array in object array.

```
przedmioty[0]=new object[6] {"test",1,1337,1,1,"test"};
```

Worked but

```
int i=0;
przedmioty[i]=new object[6] {"test",1,1337,1,1,"test"};
```

Didn't work.

Comment: Check the value of `wynikIlosc.Rows[0]["ilosc"]` and make sure that it can be cast to an `int`

Comment: select count(*) as ilosc from Przedmioty limit 1
return allways int value

Comment: As the exception states it is `System.InvalidCastException`. Try the code: `int count = 0; var success = int.TryParse(wynikIlosc.Rows[0]["ilosc"].ToString(), out count);` and see what is the result of `count` and `success` variable.

Comment: Separate your code out into individual lines and see where the exception is actually happening. I can't even tell from your question whether the error is happening on line 1 or line 2. Additionally what didn't work about your other test cases? Did it throw the exact same error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ilosc` may not be coming back as a `Type.Int32` (which is an int).  It could be coming back as a `DbType` (or `OracleDbType` or whatever database) `enum` value, like `DbType.Int32` or `OracleDbType.Decimal`.   Explicit conversion doesn't always play nice when dealing with those datatypes.  To get around this, I often use the `.ToString()` method of the result field and then use `.Parse` or `.TryParse` as my way to cast:

```
double.Parse(field[0][i].ToString());
```

Comment: Change to
DataTable     wynikIlosc=API.exported.Database.executeQueryWithResult("select count(*) as ilosc from Przedmioty limit 1");
  przedmioty= new object[int.Parse(wynikIlosc.Rows[0]["ilosc"].ToString())];
Works perfer :)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL count(*) returns a BIGINT (long C# type).

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count

Try casting to long:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn { ColumnName = "ilosc", DataType = typeof(long) });
table.Rows.Add(table.NewRow());
table.Rows[0]["ilosc"] = 3;
var test2 = new object[(long)table.Rows[0]["ilosc"]];
```